# Is there really no way to set socks or proxy in Xfce as simply as in Gnome?

Tags: networking, xfce, proxy, socks5-proxy

I've been reading some articles on how to set an HTTP proxy or a socks server with Xfce, and one of the solutions was to add some lines to `/etc/environment` and then logout and log back in. Not very nice. Moreover, my browser somehow didn't understand the seemingly plain and clear setup with the variables `ALL_PROXY` and `NO_PROXY` (both in upper and lower case), and thus stopped working altogether. Another solution was to use `dconf-editor` or the Gnome network tool, which did the trick, but only for Firefox. Somehow Firefox saw the system settings, while Vivaldi or Brave didn't (not to mention they don't have any proxy settings, but worked as needed in Gnome when I used these tools).

I was surprised that up until now there seemingly is no tool for easy global proxy/socks server setting without using either Gnome or KDE. Is this really true?